# maven ignores -f parameter

Tags: maven

Struggling with maven again and again. Now here is the problem:
I have the following structure in my project:

- pom.xml
- localpom.xml
- module1folder
- module2folder

I want to keep both pom files for several reasons. As showed in maven help, instead of using pom.xml we need to do something like this: `mvn -f localpom.xml clean install`, but what was my surprise when it continued using pom.xml, ignoring `-f` parameter. I thought maybe there is some mistakes in the localpom.xml, but no! When I removed pom.xml from the current folder `mvn -f localpom.xml clean install` had done it's work perfectly.

Do anybody has any thoughts about why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which version of maven are you using?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov, the version is 3.0.4 according to the `mvn -v`

Comment: How do you determine that maven is using `pom.xml` instead of `localpom.xml`?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov, as I said, when I launch `mvn -f localpom.xml clean install` when both .xml are in the current folder I have the output as I launched `mvn -f clean install`. After removing pom.xml from the current directory and relaunching `mvn -f localpom.xml clean install` it works as intended.

Comment: As a work around, could you define multiple profiles within `pom.xml` to produce the different builds you require? That would be the more "Maven" way.

Comment: @DuncanJones, I would do this with pleasure, but, unfortunately, that's the only possible way. Because in pom.xml I have <parent> tag specified and in localpom.xml I don't. And, as you know, <parent> tag is not allowed in the <profiles>.